# Pandas, drop duplicated rows based on other columns values

Tags: python, pandas

Example data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'file': ['file1','file1','file1','file2','file2','file2','file3','file3','file3'],
    'prop1': ['True','False','True','False','False','False','True','False','False'],
    'prop2': ['False','False','False','False','True','False','False','True','False'],
    'prop3': ['False','True','False','True','False','True','False','False','True']
})

file    prop1   prop2   prop3
0   file1   True    False   False
1   file1   False   False   True
2   file1   True    False   False
3   file2   False   False   True
4   file2   False   True    False
5   file2   False   False   True
6   file3   True    False   False
7   file3   False   True    False
8   file3   False   False   True
```

File1 have prop1 true 2 times, file2 have prop3 2 times, file3 have each of props 1 time. So i need to make another dataframe like this:

```
    file    prop
0   file1   prop1
1   file2   prop3
2   file3   diff (file3 props are different)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using `idxmax` combine `sum` to detect the `max` value

```
s=df1.set_index('file').sum(level=0)

s.idxmax(1).mask(s.eq(s.max(1),axis=0).sum(1)==3,'diff')
file
file1    prop1
file2    prop3
file3     diff
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but what if there are not exactly 3 of each files. What if there are also file4 2 times in df, is it possible to add some check to do this only for 3 times meeted files?

Comment: @Contra111 change to ==3

Comment: hi can you help please. I use your code. But i have some file meet 2 times in df, so it looks like `file6 true false false
file6 false true false` and after 1st part of your cod it looks like `file6 1.0 1.0 0` and after second part `file6 prop1` but i want to do one of the things with this file: 1. doesnt count file because it meets 2 times. 2. set it like "diff" in formated df. 3. set if like "notthree" in formated df. Or something like that because I don't need files that don't occur three times. Щr make a separate DF in which only those files that are repeated exactly three times.

Answer (score 2):

Since your data are `string` instead of `bool`, we need a little trick:

```
(df1.iloc[:,1:].eq('True')  # props are string
    .groupby(df1['file'])   # groupby each file
    .sum()                  # count the True's in each group
    .gt(1)                  # mask the column with more than 1 True
    .dot(df1.columns[1:])   # get the column name
    .replace('','diff')     # fill those files with no double True
)
```

output:

```
file
file1    prop1
file2    prop3
file3     diff
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, in example its string. but in real datagrame it is bool

Comment: Then drop `.eq('True')` would be enough.